# How to render a user link in a markdown document in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, github-flavored-markdown

I'm in the process of moving some documentation from Confluence to Azure DevOps, so I'm really new to everything Azure DevOps.

I find the Azure DevOps wiki page editor unfriendly, so I prefer to edit my markdown in Visual Studio Code.

My latest issue was to add a link to a user. I eventually discovered when experimenting in the Azure DevOps editor, that I needed to press the @ key and it would allow a search for a user.

My markdown now contains `@<My User>` and in Azure DevOps it renders correctly showing `@MyUser`.

In Visual Studio Code, in the preview pane, it renders as `@`.

Does anyone know of a Visual Studio Code extension that fixes this, so that I could see `@MyUser` in the Visual Studio Code preview pane?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the VS Code extension "[**Azure DevOps Wiki Markdown**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ni.azdo-wiki-md)".

After installing this extension, in the '**`setting.json`**' file, you need to provide your organization name and your PAT (Personal Access Token) so that the extension can connect to your organization.

[image]

---

Comment: Looked promising but after 30 mins of trying to get it to work, even using a full access token, it wouldn't show any users